# how can we save html5 canvas image to database in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I m creating product design page for e-commerce web site...
I need to save designed image from client side to database....
I tried to save but it could'nt save...and html5 canvas is new for me...

My html code..
...................

```
<div id="clothing-designer">
                        <div class="fpd-product" title="Shirt Front" data-thumbnail="images/yellow_shirt/front/preview.png">
                            <img src="./images/yellow_shirt/front/base.png" title="Base Front" data-parameters='{"x": 123, "y": 81, "colors": "#d59211", "price": 20}' />
                            <img src="./images/yellow_shirt/front/body.png" title="Hightlights" data-parameters='{"x": 249, "y": 80}' />
                            <img src="./images/yellow_shirt/front/shadows.png" title="Shadow" data-parameters='{"x": 123, "y": 81}' />
                            <span title="Any Text" data-parameters='{"x": 243, "y": 181, "removable": true, "draggable": true, "rotatable": true, "resizable": true, "colors": "#000000"}'>Default Text</span>
                            <div class="fpd-product" title="Shirt Back" data-thumbnail="images/yellow_shirt/back/preview.png">
                                <img src="./images/yellow_shirt/back/base.png" title="Base Back" data-parameters='{"x": 123, "y": 81, "colors": "#d59211", "price": 20}' />
                                <img src="./images/yellow_shirt/back/body.png" title="Hightlights" data-parameters='{"x": 277, "y": 79}' />
                                <img src="./images/yellow_shirt/back/shadows.png" title="Shadow" data-parameters='{"x": 123, "y": 81}' />
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You give little info, but here is a brief overview of the process you will need.

A full description of how to get design info from the client to your database is beyond the scope of a Stackoverflow discussion, but this example should get you started with the concepts involved.

**Convert the canvas to an imageUrl**

If you want to save the canvas content as an image you can use canvas.toDataURL() which returns a DataURL of the canvas in .png format. For example:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var dataUrl=canvas.toDataURL();
```

**Send that dataUrl back to your server with an AJAX post**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost/saveCanvasDataUrl.php",
  data: {image: dataUrl}
})
.done(function(respond){console.log("done: "+respond);})
.fail(function(respond){console.log("fail");})
.always(function(respond){console.log("always");})
```

**On the PHP side, save the incoming dataURL to a database:**

```
<?php

    if(!isset($_POST["code"])){
        die("Post was empty.");
    }

    $sql="insert into designs(image) values(:image)";

    // INSERT with named parameters
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB', "root", "myPassword");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":image",$_POST["image"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
    echo $affected_rows;

?>
```

**Alternatively...**

With this all said, it might be more useful to save the components of the design that the user created rather than an image of that design.

Create a javascript object containing the specific info about the design:

```
var item1={
    product:"shirt",
    color:"#d59211",
    price:20,
    text:"Default Text",
    textX:243,
    textY:181
}
```

Use JSON to convert that object into a string

```
var item1Json=JSON.stringify(item1);
```

Then post that useful design data to your database instead of the image.

Comment: When do I need to call the Ajax and PHP to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 Canvas' `toDataURL()` which according to the docs:

> Returns a data: URL containing a representation of the image in the format specified by type (defaults to PNG)

It is used like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('thecanvaselement');
// ...maybe some more canvas drawing operations here
var url = canvas.toDataURL();
```

The results (stored in the `url` variable) can then be sent back to the server using AJAX and then saved to your database like you would normally do.