# Saving a HTML5 canvas as an image to the server

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I'm trying to save my canvas as an image to my server but it is not working.

javascript

```
var data = canvas.toDataURL();
var picture = document.getElementById("my-picture");
```

PHP

```
$canvas = base64_decode(str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '' , $value['picture']));
file_put_contents('my_custom_path/my_custom_filename.png', $canvas);
```

this code was given to me but I am not sure how to implement the php part.

Comment: This is an often asked and answered question here on Stackoverflow.  You might try a search(!).  Here's one example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575090/how-can-we-save-html5-canvas-image-to-database-in-php/24577302#24577302

Comment: The point of asking is so that I can participate in the discussion because I do not have enough reputation to participate in other posts. The reputation system makes absolutely no sense especially if you're going to flag all my posts. You should consider removing the reputation requirement for commenting. @markE

Comment: I didn't flag your post or downvote you. I just suggest that you will find this question is successfully answered often so you might try the search box in the upper right corner. ;-)

Comment: I understand but I have looked for the question and I have found the posts you are referring to. But I am a novice at javascript/php and the answers from the other posts don't go into enough detail for me. Naturally I would just add a comment on there post but I am unable to due to my lack of reputation. @markE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Javascript/HTML is correct (make sure you are grabbing the correct POST value) try this PHP code instead:

```
$data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data);
$data = base64_decode( str_replace(' ', '+', $data) );
$success = file_put_contents('my_custom_path/my_custom_filename.png', $data);
```

Also make sure the directory that you are placing the file in is accessible.

Comment: It's creating a file but the size is 0 and I cannot open it.

Comment: If the file size is 0 I can only assume it isn't posting the data properly. In your post you show `$value['picture']` are you sure it shouldn't be `$value['data']` ?

Comment: It is when I use your code that I get a blank file image

Comment: Are you sure the user running PHP has write access to the directory you're trying to write the file to?

Comment: I have no idea but I guess I would assume they don't. I have never worked with PHP so I don't really know how to give write access.

Comment: Nevermind I'm sure they have write access @Svenskunganka