# How to save html canvas modified with sketch.js into MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, post, html5-canvas

Alright so I have **a single php page that contains an html form**. After this html form is filled out, **I'm using PHP to save the data into a MySQL database (all on the same page)**.

Within this form, I have an **HTML canvas** that I am drawing on with **Sketch.js**

http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/

```
<canvas id="tcInjuryImageFront" width="283px" height="629px" style="background-image: url('includes/images/image001.png'); float: left;"></canvas>
```

I want to save this canvas as an image and put it with the rest of the form data within my MySQL database (using PHPMyAdmin).

How would I go about doing this? I've tried the method posted here: [how can we save html5 canvas image to database in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575090/how-can-we-save-html5-canvas-image-to-database-in-php) ; however, I get the following error:

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test.com/index.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.test.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.**

when I use the following javascript function:

```
function saveCanvas()
{
var frontCanvas = document.getElementById("tcInjuryImageFront");
var dataUrl = frontCanvas.toDataURL();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://test.com/index.php",
    data: {image: dataUrl}
})
.done(function(respond){alert("done: "+respond);})
.fail(function(respond){alert("fail");})
.always(function(respond){alert("always");})
} //end saveCanvas
```

When I run this I get the alerts for **fail** and **always**. This doesn't make any sense to me because this is the exact same url that I'm currently on, so it's definitely within the same domain.

Frankly, though this method seems incorrect for my purposes anyways as I'm not trying to load this data into a new page, **I'm just trying to make it accessible in PHP within the current page so I can save it into the MySQL database with the rest of the form data.**

Ideas?

Comment: if its the same domain, try leaving off the domain

Comment: No difference, if I use index.php I get the same exact error, as if I had left the domain in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I got it. I couldn't get the info to be saved to the same page so I created a new php page and had all of this canvas code occur after the insert statement for the rest of the form data was complete.

Then I inserted the image data into a BLOB field with an update statement, and redisplayed it afterwards and the drawn sketches from sketch.js were displayed correctly.